# Formatting text displayed when QR code is scanned

Tags: qr-code

Is there any way I can format the text displayed by scanning a QR code? I know how to make a QR code, and how to format the QR code itself so it can be different colours. 
What I want to know is:

1. If the QR code decodes to the phrase "Hello World", is there any way I can make this phrase appear in blue/bold/15pt font?
2. Imagine the QR code decodes to "Here is a link for Google:" [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). Here "www.google.com" is a working link.  Is there a way I can hide the url (www.google.com) and instead display different text that links to www.google.com? Ex. Here is a link for Google: [Click Here](http://www.google.com/). 
   This will be very helpful for long urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You can have plain ASCII or UTF-8 text.  That's all the specification will allow.

You *can* use control character like `%0A` to create a newline.  But that really is about the extent of it.

If you want colour, formatting, HTML links, etc - you're best off pointing the user directly to a web page.

Comment: Thanks for your great reply. Unfortunately, the user needs to be able to scan the QR code while offline. The encoded information must be available to them with or without having the internet. So I must encode text instead of sending to a web page. If they are online, they have the option to click the link after reading all the text.

Comment: I didn't explain this in my original posting. Your response was perfect. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your second point is *rather* possible, which means most of the time it will work but it can also make the QR Code unusable (with some readers).

You can use this format: [MEBKM](https://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/developer/make/content/barcode/function/application/bookmark/). It is made for substituting a URL with a title.

[image: an example using MEBKM]

But you'd better make your QR Code data as short as possible and use a mobile website instead as suggested.

Comment: hmm maybe I'm missing something, but this still seems to show the url. I'm trying to avoid displaying the url to the user. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: there's not much you can do, you'd better use a mobile website even though that's less easy to set up